# Apps doesn´t run in the android emulator, but runs correctly in my device

Tags: android, android-emulator

My app runs perfectly in my phone, but not in the emulator.

These are the errors that shows me, I really want to know, even thought it runs on my phone, maybe one day, I will only want to emulate in the computer.
thank you

```
11-02 15:07:00.571 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus I/art: JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
11-02 15:07:00.642 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.dell.amadeus-1/lib/x86
11-02 15:07:00.660 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-02 15:07:00.661 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-02 15:07:00.661 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.dell.amadeus, PID: 2373
11-02 15:07:00.661 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dell.amadeus/com.example.dell.amadeus.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: A TaskDescription's primary color should be opaque
11-02 15:07:00.661 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
11-02 15:07:00.661 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
11-02 15:07:00.661 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
11-02 15:07:00.661 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
11-02 15:07:00.661 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-02 15:07:00.661 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
11-02 15:07:00.661 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
11-02 15:07:00.661 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-02 15:07:00.661 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
11-02 15:07:00.661 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-02 15:07:00.661 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: A TaskDescription's primary color should    be opaque
11-02 15:07:00.661 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription.<init>(ActivityManager.java:586)
11-02 15:07:00.661 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.onApplyThemeResource(Activity.java:3731)
11-02 15:07:00.661 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.initializeTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:150)
11-02 15:07:00.661 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.setTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:94)
11-02 15:07:00.661 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
11-02 15:07:00.661 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
11-02 15:07:00.661 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
11-02 15:07:00.661 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
11-02 15:07:00.661 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
11-02 15:07:00.661 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
11-02 15:07:00.661 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
11-02 15:07:00.661 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-02 15:07:00.661 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
11-02 15:07:00.661 2373-2373/com.example.dell.amadeus E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Your emulator runs Lollipop or Marshmallow, your phone is KitKat or below... see http://stackoverflow.com/q/29166809/4844216

Comment: Thank you, that solves my problem :)