# Android black screen before Splash screen in Kitkat version

Tags: android, android-theme, android-version

In my Android application I seen black screen before splash screen so that I

```
have customized app theme as follows:

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

        <!-- my custom theme. -->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash1</item>
    </style>
```

the following is work for API version 20 and below version but in kitkat version (API version 21) it open the my splash screen two times.
I could not get solution after working long time. Please help me on this.

Comment: KitKat is API 19.  API 21 is Lollipop (5.1).

Comment: Have you tried just using an activity that shows until you loaded all necessary data?

Answer (score 2):

I am getting blank screen and i found the issue that "**A TaskDescription's primary color should be opaque**", means you have to **replace your colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark** to 6 digits,

example: if you take colorPrimary = #4D607D8B remove "4D" and finally it is #607D8B. you can refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29166908/2897365

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Add a theme with the same background you are using into your application tag in the manifest file to prevent the black screen to be drawn.

**theme.xml**

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme is the default theme. -->
<style name="Theme" parent="android:style/Theme" />

<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="Theme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/my_app_background</item>

</style>
</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
        android:name="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyAppTheme" >
```