# A TaskDescription's primary color should be opaque Android 6.0

Tags: colors, android-actionbar

my code is,

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.app_icon);
        ActivityManager.TaskDescription taskDescription = new ActivityManager.TaskDescription("AppName", bm ,R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
        setTaskDescription(taskDescription);
    }
```

in `colors.xml`

```
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#FF9800</color>
```

it gives error `java.lang.RuntimeException: A TaskDescription's primary color should be opaque`

EDIT 1:

> manifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon3"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

> styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#242533</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#242533</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>                    

</style>
```

> logcat

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: co.treeline.kitetrack, PID: 18419
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{co.treeline.kitetrack/co.treeline.kitetrack.SplashScreen}: java.lang.RuntimeException: A TaskDescription's primary color should be opaque
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
               Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: A TaskDescription's primary color should be opaque
                  at android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription.<init>(ActivityManager.java:589)
                  at co.treeline.kitetrack.SplashScreen.changeMinimizedActionbarColor(SplashScreen.java:284)
                  at co.treeline.kitetrack.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:73)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

what is the problem here?

Comment: could you add your style.xml file and manifest and  full stack trace

Comment: i already tired it. that also give same error

Comment: i'm used `R.color.colorPrimaryDark` in `TaskDescricption` . what is the need of changing `colorAccent`?

Comment: Could you post full stacktrace?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue it should works

Comment: not working also added `colorAccent` to `#FFFFFF`

Comment: any other/correct way to achieve this?

Comment: I am working on this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that `TaskDescription("AppName", bm ,R.color.colorPrimaryDark)` needs colour value as parameter and you're using resource id. It is not the same, you have to get your colour via method `context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)`.

Change :

```
ActivityManager.TaskDescription taskDescription = new ActivityManager.TaskDescription("AppName", bm ,R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
```

to

```
ActivityManager.TaskDescription taskDescription = new ActivityManager.TaskDescription("AppName", bm , ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
```

Comment: Also use `ActivityManager.TaskDescription taskDescription = new ActivityManager.TaskDescription("AppName", bm, ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.app_secondary1_color));` . `getColor() is deprecated`